# Using OpsWorks + Chef

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I totally newbie using Chef (I am using OpsWorks). 
I am trying to use Jenkins Cookbook. (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins) to automate Jenkins deploy.

I used the master recipe and already installed Jenkins. 
How do I automate the other tasks (for example set a SSH Key). 
Do I need to clone the Jenkins Chef repository and create other recipes  (using the resources / providers) to automate these tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

Most community cookbooks are not designed for OpsWorks. I wouldn't go so far as to say that OpsWorks is "unsupported" but it is a very different beast from "normal Chef" and as such you'll have to figure out how to adapt things. Generally speaking OpsWorks no longer manages pulling in custom cookbooks for you (it used to be a feature but was removed for unknown reasons) so you'll need to handle vendoring the cookbook and applying it to nodes.

We do not recommend new Chef users start with OpsWorks due to their generally lackluster documentation and limited support resources.

Comment: Ok! But in case that I am using Chef. Do I  need to build other receipts (using library/resources) to automate the jenkins deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to create custom recipes to provision other resources your Jenkins server might need (such as SSH keys). Instead of forking the Jenkins cookbook and adding recipes, [create a wrapper cookbook](https://blog.chef.io/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right) and provision those extra resources in your wrapper cookbook's recipes.